# Merging tables, but ignoring duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables I want to merge:

`city1(id, city, state, zip, lat, lon, county)`

`city2(id, city, state)`

The tables contain overlapping `city` and `state`, but not primary keys. I can't figure out how to do this. `UNION` won't work, nor `INSERT IGNORE` due to the different column numbers and primary keys. So, I guess that leaves joins(left?), but I can't figure out the syntax to get it it excluding duplicates.

**A NOTE**

`UNION` will still display duplicate city/state combinations. From what I've read, `UNION` does prevent duplicates if the tables have different sizes.

**Table Create Statements**

*Column and table names have changed*

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_state_code` (`state_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29739 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `cities_extended` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41756 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE city1\G` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE city2\G` and post their output in your question.

Comment: Please clarify the Merge. Do you want to load data from `city1` into `city2`, or just run a join query ?

Comment: I want to merge data from `cities` into `cities_extended` but not keeping the rows with the same `city` and `state_code`. `id` is inconsistent between them.

Answer (score 1):

## Proposed Solution #1

```
ALTER TABLE cities          ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
ALTER TABLE cities_extended ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
CREATE TABLE cities_new
    SELECT A.city,A.state_code
    FROM cities A LEFT JOIN cities_extended B USING (city,state_code)
    WHERE B.city IS NULL
;
INSERT INTO cities_extended (city,state_code)
SELECT city,state_code FROM cities_new;
DROP TABLE cities_new;
```

## Explanation for Proposed Solution #1

#### Create Unique Indexes on (city,state_code) for both tables

```
ALTER TABLE cities          ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
ALTER TABLE cities_extended ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
```

#### Create Temp Table with rows from `cities` that's not in `cities_extended`

```
CREATE TABLE cities_new
    SELECT A.city,A.state_code
    FROM cities A LEFT JOIN cities_extended B USING (city,state_code)
    WHERE B.city IS NULL
;
```

#### Load the Temp Table into `cities`

```
INSERT INTO cities_extended (city,state_code)
SELECT city,state_code FROM cities_new;
```

#### Discard the Temp Table

```
DROP TABLE cities_new;
```

## Proposed Solution #2

```
ALTER TABLE cities_extended ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
INSERT IGNORE INTO cities_extended
(city,state_code,zip,latitude,longitude,county)
SELECT city,state_code,0,0.0,0.0,'' FROM cities;
```

## Explanation for Proposed Solution #2

`INSERT IGNORE` only works with unique indexes and primary keys. In your case, a unique index on `city,state_code` was needed for `cities_extended`.

After making such an index, you can insert all columns except `id`.

You could also include id like this

```
ALTER TABLE cities_extended ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_city_state (city,state_code);
INSERT IGNORE INTO cities_extended
(id,city,state_code,zip,latitude,longitude,county)
SELECT NULL,city,state_code,0,0.0,0.0,'' FROM cities;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!